# How can we generate a conformation prompt before deleting a comment in Django?

Tags: javascript, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I am trying to link java script and Django views, I have a comments delete view, where its functionality is good but, i need some conformation using javascript before deleting them.

I don't have knowledge regarding the Mapping Javascript and Django views. Can any one help me in writing the code?

```
@login_required
def delete_my_comment(request, pk):
    comment = get_object_or_404(Comment, pk=pk)
    if comment.user == request.user.username:
        comment.delete()
        messages.success(request, f' Your comment is deleted')
    return redirect('post-detail', pk=comment.post.id)

 <a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm mt-1 mb-1" href="{% url 'post-delete' object.id %}">Delete Post</a>
```

Can some help me in writing javascript logic for the delete conformation based on above code?
Thank you all

Answer (score 1):

The answer with generic view is great, but if you need more controll of your UI you can do this using JavaScript. Just add event listener on deleting button. If user clicks this button - some hidden html form will be displayed, by changing its display attribute to block. If you're using bootstrap it's even simpler. Read about [Bootstrap Modals](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion,, can you have any examples for the reference of how to use it and all the examples looks like html, how does it actually help me

Comment: You can see in here: [Show confirmation message before deleting](http://www.dotnetqueries.com/Article/84/show-confirmation-message-before-delete-using-bootstrap-modal-popup-in-asp-net-mvc). Ignore that part written in Java, just see how it's managed in HTML ;)

Answer (score 0):

why dont you try out django generic views, use class based views such as

class DeleteComment(LoginRequiredMixin, DeleteView):

```
model =  Comment
template_name = "delete_comment.html"
success_url = "post"
```

create a delete_comment.html with a confirmation sentence as well as a button for submit and anchor for cancel , this should do fine

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, i know the way of solution that you have proposed but i want to do it with javascipt, do you know how can we do it with javascript?